# Azure Functions fails to receive Azure Queue messages [.net Core 2.0]

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-servicebus-queues

When I updated my Azure Functions project to .net core 2.0, it started failing to trigger upon a message on my Queue.

**TranslatorAPI.cs**

```
public static class TranslatorAPI
{
    [FunctionName("TranslatorAPI")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("Translator")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
    {
        //breakpoint here, but never hit
        CallTranslator callTranslator = new CallTranslator();

        //something
    }
}
```

**local.setting.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME": "Production",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~1",
    "ScmType": "None",
    "WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED": "False",
    "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE": "readwrite",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "<Key>",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "6.5.0",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<Key>",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "<ShareName>",
    "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME": "<Functions'Name>",
    "<ServiceBusInstanceName>_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS": "Endpoint=<ConnectionString>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<Key>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<AccountName>;AccountKey=<Key>;BlobEndpoint=<BlobURL>;TableEndpoint=<TableURL>;QueueEndpoint=<QueueURL>;FileEndpoint=<FileURL>"
  }
}
```

**Workaround:**

With the latest NuGet package "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" 3.0.0-beta4, there is [a  known issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/624) with handling an extension for ServiceBus connection and project build is to fail at establishing a path for the ServiceBus metadata. Updating these packages from the source [Azure App Service](http://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2):

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs: 3.0.0-beta4-11131
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions: 3.0.0-beta4-10578
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator: 1.0.0-beta3
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServisBus: 3.0.0-beta4-11131
```

enabled the build succeeded. However, it still cannot receive a message from my queue. Here's the log of function console.

```
[2018/01/20 0:22:38] Reading host configuration file '<ProjectPath>\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\host.json'
[2018/01/20 0:22:38] Host configuration file read:
[2018/01/20 0:22:38] {}
[2018/01/20 0:22:40] Loading custom extension 'HttpExtensionConfiguration'
[2018/01/20 0:22:40] Unable to load custom extension type for extension 'HttpExtensionConfiguration' (Type: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpExtensionConfiguration, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`).The type does not exist or is not a valid extension. Please validate the type and assembly names.
[2018/01/20 0:22:40] Loading custom extension 'ServiceBusExtensionConfig'
[2018/01/20 0:22:40] Loaded custom extension: ServiceBusExtensionConfig from '<ProjectPath>\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\bin\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.dll'
[2018/01/20 0:22:41] Generating 1 job function(s)
[2018/01/20 0:22:42] Starting Host (HostId=<PCName>-1149239943, Version=2.0.11415.0, ProcessId=12536, Debug=False, ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~1)
[2018/01/20 0:22:44] Found the following functions:
[2018/01/20 0:22:44] <Functions'Name>.TranslatorAPI.Run
[2018/01/20 0:22:44]
[2018/01/20 0:22:44] Job host started
[2018/01/20 0:22:44] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '<ID>'.
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
```

Although it fails to read an extenstion for http trigger type, it succeeds to generate TranslatorAPI.Run.

So what would be a problem here?

**EDIT**

I assumed the method failed to get the connection string, so I changed the method argument to

```
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("Translator", Connection = "<ServiceBusInstanceName>_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
```

Then the error changed into

```
[2018/01/20 1:32:57] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'TranslatorAPI.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Failed to validate Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK <ServiceBusInstanceName>_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS connection string. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection string is not formatted correctly. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=841340 for details about configuring Microsoft Azure Storage connection strings.
```

Now it seems say my connection string for the ServiceBus is wrong *based on the validation of connection string for Azure Storage Account*. I'm not sure how to understand what's this meaning and to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your connection string for the QueueTrigger is actually a service bus connection string. The QueueTrigger connection string should be in the following format: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

If you did want to use the service bus queue, you can try using the [ServiceBusTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) instead!

Comment: That's an easy mistake... Indeed I wanted to use ServiceBus Queue and it was different from Queue. Thanks :)